# Understanding the solution to the differential equation $\dot{x} = x^2\cos{t^2}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking at the Haberman book on ODEs, chapter 1.3 problem 11. The problem is to find the solution of the separable first order ODE.

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = x^2\cos{t^2}
$$

Now the posted solution uses the definite integral, where $\bar{x}, \bar{t}$ are the dummy variables of integration.

$$
\int_{1}^{x} \bar{x}^{-2} d \bar{x}=\int_{0}^{t} \cos \left(\bar{t}^{2}\right) d \bar{t}
$$

My question was how to make the argument about the integration bounds on the integral on the LHS, $\int_{1}^{x} \bar{x}^{-2} d \bar{x}$. I understand that as $x \rightarrow 0$, the value of $\frac{1}{x^2}$ will explode. But it still seems a bit odd that I did an operation on the left hand side that is asymmetric with the operation on the right hand side. I also understand that $cos(\bar{t})$ can only vary between 1 and -1, so that would also limit the range of the left hand side integral as well. Can anyone provide a more rigorous justification for the change in the bounds of the integral or the asymmetry in the bounds of the integration. Thanks.

Comment: I fixed up your title to be a bit more plain English, but wanted to note that this is not a linear differential equation.

Comment: @CameronWilliams haha, thanks. Yeah you are totally right, the book is on linear odes, but the particular example is not linear. I am trying to review the ode stuff so that I can look at more control theory applications, so it is slowly coming back to me.

Comment: No worries! I just figured I'd point it out to prevent any misconceptions in the future (if there were any and it wasn't just a brain fart). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also just do it as an indefinite integral and the integration constant will be determined by the initial/boundary conditions:
$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2}=\int \cos t^2dt$$
$$\frac1x=-\int\cos t^2dt+C_1$$
another way of thinking about it would be that you want to integrate both sides over the same region of $t$, so you could do:
$$\int_{x(t_0)}^{x(t)}\frac{d\bar{x}}{\bar{x}^2}=\int_{t_0}^t\cos \bar{t}^2d\bar{t}$$

Comment: Yeah, this makes more sense. In the book they just had one example, but not much explanation. Yes it makes more sense when I think of $x$ as a function of $t$.

Answer (score 4):

For this Problem Haberman gives some initial condition : $x(0)=1$. So that we have:
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = x^2\cos{t^2}$$
$$\frac{dx}{x^2} = \cos{t^2} \, dt$$
$$\int_{x(0)}^{x(t)}\frac{d\bar x}{\bar x^2} =\int_0^t \cos{\bar t^2} \, d\bar t$$
$$\int_{1}^{x(t)}\frac{d \bar x}{\bar x^2} =\int_0^t \cos{\bar t^2} \, d\bar t$$